# how do concat and drop duplicated columns that have na values and not deleting other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I don't know how to do it properly I've tried many things like using concat, merge and still can't find the answer. I was using selenium and got this data frame anyway

I'm using other methods like `pd.concat`, `df.merge`, and `df.extract`, still can't find the right way for this dataframe

here's my data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'player': {0: 'trent', 1: 'neT', 2: 'valyn', 3: 'tex', 4: 'JonahP', 5: 'XXiF', 6: 'Genghsta', 7: 'clear', 8: 'steel', 9: 'Exalt', 10: 'trent', 11: 'neT', 12: 'valyn', 13: 'tex', 14: 'JonahP', 15: 'XXiF', 16: 'Genghsta', 17: 'clear', 18: 'steel', 19: 'Exalt'}, 'XXiF': {0: 4.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 1.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'Genghsta': {0: 2.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 2.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'clear': {0: 3.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 6.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 4.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'steel': {0: 4.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 4.0, 3: 6.0, 4: 3.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'Exalt': {0: 5.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 3.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'trent': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 2.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 3.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'neT': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 1.0, 6: 3.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 7.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'valyn': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 4.0, 6: 6.0, 7: 4.0, 8: 6.0, 9: 1.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'tex': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 5.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 2.0, 9: 1.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'JonahP': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 2.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 3.0, 9: 2.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'XXiF.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 2.0, 11: 5.0, 12: 2.0, 13: 5.0, 14: 1.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'Genghsta.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 1.0, 11: 2.0, 12: 5.0, 13: 4.0, 14: 3.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'clear.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 1.0, 11: 5.0, 12: 5.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 3.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'steel.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 2.0, 11: 3.0, 12: 7.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 3.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'Exalt.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 3.0, 11: 3.0, 12: 4.0, 13: 2.0, 14: 2.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'trent.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 3.0, 16: 1.0, 17: 3.0, 18: 2.0, 19: 2.0}, 'neT.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 2.0, 16: 2.0, 17: 5.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 0.0}, 'valyn.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 4.0, 16: 0.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 5.0, 19: 1.0}, 'tex.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 2.0, 16: 3.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 1.0}, 'JonahP.1': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 1.0, 16: 2.0, 17: 2.0, 18: 3.0, 19: 4.0}, 'game_id': {0: 114717, 1: 114717, 2: 114717, 3: 114717, 4: 114717, 5: 114717, 6: 114717, 7: 114717, 8: 114717, 9: 114717, 10: 114718, 11: 114718, 12: 114718, 13: 114718, 14: 114718, 15: 114718, 16: 114718, 17: 114718, 18: 114718, 19: 114718}})
```

I'm expecting the duplicate column that has `na` filled with another column that shares the same column title

here's my desired output

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'player': {0: 'trent', 1: 'neT', 2: 'valyn', 3: 'tex', 4: 'JonahP', 5: 'XXiF', 6: 'Genghsta', 7: 'clear', 8: 'steel', 9: 'Exalt', 10: 'trent', 11: 'neT', 12: 'valyn', 13: 'tex', 14: 'JonahP', 15: 'XXiF', 16: 'Genghsta', 17: 'clear', 18: 'steel', 19: 'Exalt'}, 'XXiF': {0: 4.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 1.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 2.0, 11: 5.0, 12: 2.0, 13: 5.0, 14: 1.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'Genghsta': {0: 2.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 2.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 1.0, 11: 2.0, 12: 5.0, 13: 4.0, 14: 3.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'clear': {0: 3.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 6.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 4.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 1.0, 11: 5.0, 12: 5.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 3.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'steel': {0: 4.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 4.0, 3: 6.0, 4: 3.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 2.0, 11: 3.0, 12: 7.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 3.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'Exalt': {0: 5.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 3.0, 5: float('nan'), 6: float('nan'), 7: float('nan'), 8: float('nan'), 9: float('nan'), 10: 3.0, 11: 3.0, 12: 4.0, 13: 2.0, 14: 2.0, 15: float('nan'), 16: float('nan'), 17: float('nan'), 18: float('nan'), 19: float('nan')}, 'trent': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 2.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 3.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 3.0, 16: 1.0, 17: 3.0, 18: 2.0, 19: 2.0}, 'neT': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 1.0, 6: 3.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 7.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 2.0, 16: 2.0, 17: 5.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 0.0}, 'valyn': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 4.0, 6: 6.0, 7: 4.0, 8: 6.0, 9: 1.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 4.0, 16: 0.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 5.0, 19: 1.0}, 'tex': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 5.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 2.0, 9: 1.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 2.0, 16: 3.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 1.0}, 'JonahP': {0: float('nan'), 1: float('nan'), 2: float('nan'), 3: float('nan'), 4: float('nan'), 5: 2.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 3.0, 9: 2.0, 10: float('nan'), 11: float('nan'), 12: float('nan'), 13: float('nan'), 14: float('nan'), 15: 1.0, 16: 2.0, 17: 2.0, 18: 3.0, 19: 4.0}, 'game_id': {0: 114717, 1: 114717, 2: 114717, 3: 114717, 4: 114717, 5: 114717, 6: 114717, 7: 114717, 8: 114717, 9: 114717, 10: 114718, 11: 114718, 12: 114718, 13: 114718, 14: 114718, 15: 114718, 16: 114718, 17: 114718, 18: 114718, 19: 114718}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html) after making group of columns :

```
out = (df.rename(lambda x: x.split(".")[0], axis=1)
                   .groupby(level=0, axis=1, sort=False).first())
```

Ouptut :

```
print(out)

      player  XXiF  Genghsta  clear  steel  Exalt  trent  neT  valyn  tex  JonahP  game_id
0      trent  4.00      2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114717
1        neT  4.00      3.00   4.00   1.00   1.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114717
2      valyn  1.00      3.00   6.00   4.00   2.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114717
3        tex  4.00      4.00   2.00   6.00   4.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114717
4     JonahP  1.00      2.00   4.00   3.00   3.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114717
5       XXiF   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   2.00 1.00   4.00 5.00    2.00   114717
6   Genghsta   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   1.00 3.00   6.00 2.00    1.00   114717
7      clear   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   3.00 1.00   4.00 2.00    1.00   114717
8      steel   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   1.00 0.00   6.00 2.00    3.00   114717
9      Exalt   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   1.00 7.00   1.00 1.00    2.00   114717
10     trent  2.00      1.00   1.00   2.00   3.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114718
11       neT  5.00      2.00   5.00   3.00   3.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114718
12     valyn  2.00      5.00   5.00   7.00   4.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114718
13       tex  5.00      4.00   1.00   1.00   2.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114718
14    JonahP  1.00      3.00   3.00   3.00   2.00    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN     NaN   114718
15      XXiF   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   3.00 2.00   4.00 2.00    1.00   114718
16  Genghsta   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   1.00 2.00   0.00 3.00    2.00   114718
17     clear   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   3.00 5.00   1.00 1.00    2.00   114718
18     steel   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   2.00 1.00   5.00 1.00    3.00   114718
19     Exalt   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   2.00 0.00   1.00 1.00    4.00   114718
```